# How do I suppress nested collections when instancing?

Tags: instances, collections

[image]
[image]
Here I have a collection which includes a nested collection. Next to it I have a collection instance. When I suppress the nested collection, I would like for the collection instance to reflect that change. Is there a clever way to do this?